# Typescipt :typing the props passed by a wrapper component in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a wrapper component A which is able to add props to children like this

```
interface AProps {
   fooProp: string
}

const A : FunctionComponent<AProps> = (props)=>{
   const [someState, setSomeState] = useState("");//local state i want to pass to children
   const {children} = props;

   //...some other code setting someState

   // type guard making the compiler happy
   if (!React.isValidElement(children){
      return <></>
   }

   return (
     <>
         React.cloneElement(React.Children.only(children, {someState})
     </>
   )
};
```

Now i want to use it with a component X which needs a `someState:string` prop like this

```
<A fooProp="foobar">
   <X/>
</A
```

But Typescript is complaining that X is not provided with required someState prop;
How do i make him aware that component A is able to pass the `someState` prop to its children ?

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the prop as optional:

```
    interface XProps {
        someState?: string;
    }

    class X extends React.Component<XProps> { ... }
```

#### EDIT

Maybe a better approach is HOC (High Order Component), with no need for `React.cloneElement`

```
interface AProps {
   fooProp: string
}
interface XProps {
   someState: string;
}

function withSomeState(X: React.Component<XProps>) {
    const A: FunctionComponent<AProps> = (props) => {
       const [someState, setSomeState] = useState("");//local state i want to pass to children

       //...some other code setting someState

       // type guard making the compiler happy
       if (!React.isValidElement(X){
          return <></>
       }

       return (
         <X {someState} />
       );
    }
    return A;
}
```

```
const A = withSomeState(X);

<A fooProp="foobar" />
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's more a workaround than a real solution (with checking). Do you think there is no other solution ?

Comment: Thank you for the HOC suggestion. I wonder what's the real difference between the two approaches since "aesthetically" the parent/child way seems more elegant, but the HOC makes more sense on the Typescript perspective.

Comment: @Vincent J yes the main benefit of HOC is for TypeScript. The type of the wrapped component is clearly known at compile time, while if passed as children in the other approach, it is unknown until runtime, thus more dynamic in nature, something TypeScript is not happy of.

Comment: I have thought of something. When using a wrapper component, AFAIK, under the hood JSX is transpiled with the outer component function using the result of the inner (child) component function as a parameter. So the inner component is executed before the outer component. So the first time the three is rendered, the inner function is executed with the outer function "state" no yet available, so your first advice to mark the prop as optional was the correct answer to the wrapper problem. Am i correct in my understanding ?

Comment: @VincentJ  The outer and inner components can communicate via the HOC. Use a second parameter passed to the HOC constructor to pass data to share. You can even use a function for more flexible communication, as demonstrated by ReactJS docs.